# Automatic creation of subdomains for user's page in liferay

Tags: subdomain, liferay, liferay-6

When a new user is added to liferay a public page can be created automatically for him.
Where should I look in the source of Liferay to implement such a functionnality ?
Or maybe it's already possible by configuration? If it is so how could I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically this is done in `UserLocalServiceImpl.addUserWithWorkflow(...)`, but depending on what you really need, you can do part of what you ask for through configuration:

When you create a UserGroup, you can edit the "pages" (or site template) for a usergroup. These pages will be copied/linked to a user's personal site if the user is member of that usergroup. In ControlPanel/Portal/PortalSettings you can choose this usergroup to be the default user group for all newly created users, so that they all get those pages.

Now this doesn't assign a subdomain (like a virtual host) that you mention in the title of this question. If you want to assign a virtual host to the site (called "group" in technical terms when you dig into java code), you'll have to override the method given above (e.g. through a hook that overrides `UserLocalService`) and configures the user's site/group with a virtual host. However, the UI does not allow to configure virtual hosts for user's sites, but you might be able to do this through the API, e.g. programmatically

If it's enough for you, you can also just implement a blank redirection from http://username.example.com (wildcard on 'username') to http://www.example.com/web/username - e.g. use Apache's mod_rewrite

Comment: " the UI does not allow to configure virtual hosts for user's sites" :|

Comment: Steps you introduce i still applying, but now i define .htaccess file in tomcat to map subdomain to url(user1.myoffice.com to myoffice.com/web/user1), but when user have own domain, i must configure to map to user1.myoffice.com

Comment: Thank for your attention, if no more answer in 7 days, i will mark your answer as answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i must follow that: http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/10268877.
I just want to user UI, so i must custom portlet to solve that :|